# Is it possible to avoid using "static" when call variable from another class?

Tags: java, class

Is it able to avoid using "static" when call variable from another class? thank you very much

Here is my code.

```
class Hello {
  public static String say = "Hello World";  //I using static       
  public void born() {                    
    System.out.println(say);
  }
}

public class SayHello extends Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello myHello = new Hello();
    myHello.born();
    System.out.println(say);

  }
```

The Output:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

If I use `public String say = "Hello World";`

it output `Hello World null`

AnyIdea to avoid using "static" when call variable from another class?
thank you very much

Comment: why you want to avoid using static? what is your problem?

Comment: you can't directly access a variable of other class

Comment: @user1583465 You can if the variable is static, or if it's a public instance variable. In OP's example, making `say` non-static and accessing it like `myHello.say`works.

Comment: I mean without classname/class object

Comment: @user1583465 But that doesn't apply in this case. Notice that in OP's code there are two classes and one extends the other. The string `say` is a member of both classes as it is declared in the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `static`, it will not compile. Static fields can be marked `private`, if you want to hide them. So then they are reachable by all **instances** of the class `Hello` only. The proper way of modifying or getting would be:

```
class Main extends Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Hello myHello = new Hello();
    myHello.born();
    // System.out.println(say); //doesn't allow access
    // System.out.println(Hello.say); //doesn't allow access
    System.out.println(myHello.getSay());
  }
 
}

class Hello {
  private static String say = "Hello World";  //private      
  public void born() {                    
    System.out.println(say);
  }

 public String getSay() {
  return say;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is common to all the instances (or objects) of the class because it is a class level variable. In other words you can say that only a single copy of static variable is created and shared among all the instances of the class.

So if you don't want to use static, then you can't use it in the other instances of class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't declare it static you can reference it from an instance: `myHello.say`.
It is the same as for calling a function.

```
public class SayHello extends Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello myHello = new Hello();
    myHello.born();
    System.out.println(myHello.say);
  }
}
```

---

For a constant, ie. a String that never changes and is the same for all instances of the class, it makes sense to declare it static and use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mark the string as `static` you will get a compilation error because when you do `System.out.println(say)` in the `main` method you are using `say` in a static context (since the `main` method must be static).

If you remove `System.out.println(say);` and just leave `myHello.born();` then there's no need for `say` to be static because you'll only be using it from non-static methods (i.e. the `born()` method). You can see it in [this example](https://jdoodle.com/ia/3Gk) where I commented that line and defined `say` as not being static.

Another option would be to make the `println` like this, since the variable is public: `System.out.println(myHello.say);`